# Can we use BindingResult for REST API in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Usually, BindingResult is used in Spring MVC for the form validation. Recently I came to know that some developers are using BindingResult in the Spring REST API as well. I went through the official document but it's not clear to me whether it would be allowed to use BindingResult in REST API or not.

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: Yes. It is used to add the validation and binding errors, so you can handle them in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is allowed to use `BindingResult` in a RestAPI, especially if you have a Front-End and you want to do the validation of data in the back end.
A very simple example:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity signUp(@Valid @RequestBody RegisteringUserDto registeringDto, BindingResult bindingResult)
{

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        bindingResult
                .getFieldErrors()
                .forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getField() + ": " + f.getDefaultMessage()));

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return authService.signUp(registeringDto);
}
```

This is just printing the errors in the Console, but you can send them to the front end via the `ResponseEntity`.